# Syntax for Using JavaScript for HTML Attribut Values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace the value of an html element's attribute with javascript. I'm pretty sure I've seen it done before, but I'm not sure how the syntax works on such things. Example:

```
<a href="javascript:bookmarksite('Website Name', "<script type="text/javascript">document.write(location.href);
</script>')">Click Here to Bookmark this Page</a>
```

Comment: This might be helpful: [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:
HTML:

```
<a id="link" href="#">Click me</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "page.html");
```

Comment: This changes only a property of the element, OP wants to change the value of an attribute : (.

Answer (score 0):

Unobtrusive JavaScript is always a nice way to handle these kinds of things:

```
(function(d){
    var modern = function(){
        return(d.addEventListener);
    }, event = function(obj, evt, fn){
        if(modern()) {
            obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
        } else {
            obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
        }
    }, load = function(fn){
        if(modern()) {
            d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function go(){
                d.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", go, false);
                fn();
            }, false);
        } else {
            d.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function go(){
                if(d.readyState === "complete") {
                    d.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", build);
                    fn();
                }
            });
        }
    }, init = function(){
        var link = d.getElementById("bookmark_link");
        event(link, "click", function(e){
            bookmarksite("Website Name", location.href);
            // Set attribute(s) here
            link.setAttribute("href", "whatever_you_want.html");
        });
    };
    load(init);
})(document);
```

Then the in the link:

```
<a href="#" id="bookmark_link">Bookmark this page</a>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ended up using php instead.

<a href="javascript:bookmarksite('Site Name', 'http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>')" title="Bookmark Name of Website">Click here to Bookmark!</a>